# How to omit `default` entry when iterating over local JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm importing a local JSON file like

```
import * as RULES from './json/rules.json';
```

If I then iterate over its entries via

```
const rules = {};
Object.entries(RULES).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    rules[key] = {};
    value.forEach((obj) => {
        rules[key][obj.tag] = obj;
    });
});
```

I get

```
TypeError: value.forEach is not a function
```

That probably is because I see there's a `default` entry being automatically added to `RULES` that contains the whole file contents again.

How can I get rid of that `default` entry, or at least iterate over everything else than it?

Comment: Just use that "default export" instead: `import RULES from '…'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import it like this:

```
import RULES from './json/rules.json';
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you elaborate a bit more? Like what's the difference to the `* as` syntax / purpose of the `default` entry? I'd also appreciate a link to some official docs about that.

Comment: The `* as` syntax is intended to be used with modules, not with JSON files. When in a module file, if you use `export default function defaultFunction () {}`, the `defaultFunction` will be exported as the default. If you use just `export function otherFunction`, you will be able to import `otherFunction` using `import { otherFunction } from './module.js'`. If you use `import * as module from './module.js'`, you will have `module.otherFunction` and `module.default`.

Comment: Here is some doc about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import